# Can BERT takes more than 2 sentences for word embeddings?

Tags: nlp, topic-modeling, bert-language-model

I'm trying to implement BERT word embedding to LDA topic model. The corpus consists of multiple sentences(more than two). I noticed BERT Model from hugging face requires segmentation id which differentiates sentences.

Is BertModel capable for more than two sentences?

If so, how to assign segment ids to tokens in different sentences?

Comment: Nope, BERT can take as input either one or two sentences and uses the special token [SEP] to differentiate them. Not more than that. Hope that helps!